# Coq file generated by WP does not compile

Tags: coq, frama-c

I have installed frama-c (18.0) and coqide (8.9) through opam (plus other needed dependencies of course, but that may not be the matter here). Well the point is I simply installed it through opam, not done anything else strange (and I didn't see any particular instruction that I should do otherwise).

Frama-c works as expected when I use Alt-ergo with WP, but if I try to use coq or coqide instead of Alt-ergo, then I get the following error for each goal that Qed does not manage to prove immediately:

```
[wp] 13 goals scheduled
[wp] [Coq] 'Qed.v' compilation failed.
------------------------------------------------------------
--- Coqc (stderr) :
------------------------------------------------------------
File "/tmp/wp7fe5dc.dir/coqwp/Qed.v", line 27, characters 8-17:
Error:
Cannot find a physical path bound to logical path matching suffix bool.

------------------------------------------------------------
[wp] [Coq] Goal typed_nondet_loop_inv_preserved : Failed
  Compilation of 'Qed.v' failed.
```

As a note, before displaying the error, it manages to compile some other .v files. I have tried to open manually the files in coqide, and I get the same result. For the record, here are the lines coq complains about:

```
Require bool.Bool.
Require int.Int.
Require int.Abs.
Require int.ComputerDivision.
Require real.Real.
Require real.RealInfix.
Require real.FromInt.
```

I have also tried to downgrade coq a bit, but not lower than 8.7 (as otherwise opam complains of incompatible base installation package and I don't really want to screw up my installation), and got the same result.

If someone would have an idea of what is causing that and how I can get to set it up that correctly, that'd be nice. Even if for what I'm doing with it for now, Alt-ergo is sufficient, I would have liked to play a bit with coq to see how it can be used.

Regards,

--

Vincent Penelle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, indeed you need `coq` < `8.8` (e.g. `8.7.2`) if you want to use it with Frama-C/WP, as newer versions are not supported for the moment.

Second, the order in which you have installed your packages is relevant. In particular, if the appropriate version of `coq` has been installed after `frama-c`, `WP` did not compile and install its coq libraries, which are the ones that are missing here. Thus, you may want to do `opam reinstall frama-c` to compile the package against a compatible `coq` version.

Comment: Hi,
Many thanks for the answer. It was indeed that.
And  sorry for the silly question by the way, I thought I had tried that, it seems I forgot to recompile frama-c afterwards.
Regards,

Comment: Glad to have helped. Your question was not silly (I upvoted it ): WP could at the very least provide a more helpful error message (e.g. a warning about missing Coq libraries) in cases like that, and `frama-c`'s `opam` package could refine a bit its optional dependencies.